# How to add multiple subviews to my iOS view in one line of code? (via "monkeypatching" an `addSubviews` instance method to UIView perhaps?)

Tags: ios, cocoa, subview, addsubview, monkeypatching

lets just say I had just one `UILabel` subview element & one `UITextView` subview element inside of a given ViewController.m's `viewDidLoad` method like so:

```
UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 140, 280, 40)];
name.text = @"Name: Eric";
UITextView *bio = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 190, 280, 80)];
bio.text = "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature fro...";
```

In a normal fashion I could add them one at a time:

```
[self.view addSubview:name];
[self.view addSubview:bio];
```

But if there were several dozen or perhaps hundreds of UI components, adding each of them one at time would add dozens to hundreds of lines of code to my project.

Coming from a ruby background, I believe brevity is very important. Is there any way to pass in my UI elements as an array like so?:

```
[self.view addSubviews:@[name, bio]];
```

It might be a little early for me to start patching iOS's libraries at boot time but that would definitely be an acceptable solution to me.

Coming from a ruby/rails template of understanding, I'm wondering, is there something equivalent to Rail's `/initializers` folder in iOS applications? FYI non/pre-rails folks, the `/initializers` folder in rails is scanned by rails at the beginning of any rails session, and all code inside its `.rb` files is executed before anything else in rails is loaded aside from the dependencies libraries which are loaded just before that. Thus the `ActiveRecord` gem (library) for example could then be reinstantiated in an initializer and be amended to at that point. I know Objective C is immutable in a lot of cases though and don't know if that would be a problem.

Existing Cocoa library methods are of course preferred.

In ruby I'd probably patch the method to UIViewController maybe a little something like this:

```
class UIViewController
  def addSubviews(subviews)
    subviews.each {|obj| self.view.addSubview(obj) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of creating a function and then use that function with a for loop?

Comment: Just loop through the array.

Comment: @ElTomato yes but I'm so green with objective C I don't think I even know how to do that, and if I do its more "hidden potential" than working knowledge if you know what I mean. in

Comment: Does Apple allow iOS Developers to patch methods onto Core iOS classes in App Store approved applications?

Comment: @boulder_ruby Yes. You could create a category on UIView for this. When creating a category though, you want to prefix your method name so you don't conflict with other people's categories. So you would call the method something like blr_addSubviews (blr being short for boulder_ruby, but you would most likely pick something based on your company name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) on `UIView`.

File --> New --> File --> Objective-C category. Name it something like `EasyAdditionOfSubviews`, make it a category on `UIView`.

**UIView+EasyAdditionOfSubviews.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (EasyAdditionOfSubviews)

- (void)addSubviews:(NSArray *)views;

@end
```

**UIView+EasyAdditionOfSubviews.m**

```
#import "UIView+EasyAdditionOfSubviews.h"

@implementation UIView (EasyAdditionOfSubviews)

- (void)addSubviews:(NSArray *)views
{
    for (UIView *view in views) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            [self addSubview:view];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

This way, you just `#import UIView+EasyAdditionOfSubviews.h` anywhere you want to be able to add an array of views at a time.

And you're better off making sure that what you're passing to `addSubview:` is indeed a `UIView`, otherwise you risk a crash (for example, try passing it an `NSArray`).

But to address your wider concern:

> But if there were several dozen or perhaps hundreds of UI components,
>   adding each of them one at time would add dozens to hundreds of lines
>   of code to my project.

If you're building a UI programmatically, you want to be exactly sure what, how, and when subviews are added to a view; it's perfectly fine to be explicit when adding a subview to a view.

As a matter of fact, your workaround to not explicitly adding the subview to its superview is... to explicitly add it to an array, which you then add to the superview. Not good for brevity!

Comment: where would I put this inside of my iOS application source code file system and where would I have to reference it to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming subViews is an array, you could do:

```
[subViews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [superview addSubview:obj];
}];
```

As @pranav mentions, an alternative is to use the for..in syntax:

```
for (UIView* view in subViews) {
    [superview addSubview:view];
}
```

Comment: Using for…in should be cleaner, i.e., `for (NSArray *subview in subviews)`

Comment: @DaveWood haha no problem, I'm all tweaked out on Cocoa so couldn't help but edit it